# Styling repeat buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the following template to style the repeat buttons for text-box's scroll bar:

```
 <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                    <!--HERE WE ADJUST PROPERTIES ON TOP AND BOTTOM BUTTONS -->
                                    <Border x:Name="Border"  CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" BorderThickness="0" >
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStopCollection>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                    </GradientStopCollection>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStopCollection>
                                                        <!--HERE WE SET THE KEYS COLOR-->
                                                        <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                                                    </GradientStopCollection>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#79B0D4" />
                                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="{Binding Content,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                                            <Path.Fill>
                                                <!--HERE WE SET THE ARROW COLOR-->
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#79B0D4"/>
                                            </Path.Fill>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
```

However, this template modifies both, top and bottom button at the same time. Is there a way to somehow 'unlink' two buttons, and then, for instance change only corners on top button, or the size of only the top button?

Comment: You can *completely* re-template TextBox/ScrollBar (looking at previous question). Not going to be easy, but it's the only way to style upper/bottom repeat buttons individually. Have a look how *themes* are created [here](https://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/) (download, compile and see at run-time how themes are looking, then go into sources to see how re-templating is done).